# What is the Go equivalent of Python's "is" operator?

Tags: python, reference, go, instance

How do I determine whether 2 variables refer to the same instance in Go? More specifically, that a mutation to the value of one variable would effect the value of the other variable also.

To further refine the question: How would I determine when 2 variables would satisfy the "is" operator per CPython:

```
a is b
```

Comment: The question is open to quite a bit of interpretation.  Go has a number cases where a type may contain a pointer or internal reference to other data.  Are you interested in a specific case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, *all* values are references (i.e. pointers) to objects. You can never get an object itself as a value. The `is` operator compares two values, which are pointers, for pointer equality; whereas the `==` operator compares two such pointers, for equality of the objects pointed to.

In Go, it's a little more complicated. Go has pointers, as well as other non-pointer types (boolean, number types, strings, arrays, slices, structs, functions, interfaces, maps, channels). It doesn't make sense to ask for pointer equality for non-pointer types. (What would it mean? What would it accomplish?)

So to have the equivalent situation as Python, let's put all of our values behind pointers, and so all variables are pointers. (There is a convention in many Go libraries of a "New" function that creates a pointer type; and the methods also operate on the pointer type; so this is compatible with that convention.) Then (if `a` and `b` are pointers) `a == b` in Go would compare two such pointers for pointer equality; and you can use `*a == *b` to compare the underlying values, if they are comparable.

Go also has several non-pointer reference types: slices, maps, functions, and channels. Channels are comparable using `==` for whether they are the same channel. However, slices, maps, and functions cannot be compared; it may be possible using reflection though.

Comment: The compiler seems to have some optimization to eliminate duplicate allocations, so if you allocate two structs exactly the same in adjacent lines of code, the compiler can actually give you two pointers to the same memory (likely only if you don't modify them) It broke a test of mine. Also some testing libraries seem to compare pointers as the underlying values (testify), so assert.Equal(p1, p2) is not the same as assert.True(p1 == p2), that broke the same test...

Answer (score 4):

EDIT : I'm not sure about what you want. If it's about the equality of variables or the identity of variable values. This answer is for the second one ("2 variables refer to the same instance " of value). If I misunderstood, I'll remove this answer.

`==` is what you want, I think.

If the type of a and b is pointer, then `a==b` means that a and b are pointers to the same value.

The following program prints `false` :

```
package main

import "fmt"

type test struct {
    a int
}

func main() {

    b := &test{2}
    c := &test{2}
    fmt.Println(c == b)

}
```

While this prints `true` :

```
    b := &test{2}
    c := b
    fmt.Println(c == b)
```

c==b is a sufficient condition for that changing c.a changes b.a

Comment: Would this work for reference types like interfaces, slices, maps and such?

Answer (score 0):

In case of non interface and non function types it is possible to compare pointers for equality. Non pointer types cannot share instances, OTOH.